# Как вытащить из geocode координаты и/или область подсказки

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, geocode

```
var QUERY = 'Москва Лесная';
//вызываю 
var promise = ymaps.geocode(QUERY, {results: 3});

//получаю подсказки
promise.then(
    function (res){
       // Далее мне нужно получить координаты точки или область 
       // Две следующие строчки не срабатывают!!!
       console.log(res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('boundedBy'));
       console.log(res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates());
      // Иду другим путем
      console.log(res.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[0].GeoObject.Point.pos);
      // Но в этом поле лежат какие-то обрезанные координаты и при центровке по ним 
      // карта уезжает в Африку, пробовал менять координаты  местами - результат тот же

  }
);
```

Comment: В вашем коде делается вызов Геокодера, который не подходит в качестве поисковых подсказок - не будет нормально работать и быстро приведет к бану из-за превышения бесплатных лимитов.
Как работать с результатами Геокодера, показано [в примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/direct_geocode?from=SO)

Comment: Если получать подсказки через suggest, то этот метод не выдает координаты и все равно придется их определять через gecode().

В присланном Вами примере вроде все то же самое, что делаю я , но у меня почему-то res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates()
не срабатывает :((

Comment: Лучше для подсказок использовать саджест, а уже выбранный вариант геокодировать. Геокодер не умеет корректно обрабатывать частичный ввод и по условиям использования требует отображения результатов геокодирования на карте.
Ваш код у меня заработал https://jsfiddle.net/wm0f2k2e/ попробуйте отлавливать ошибки, когда промисс реджектится

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
С кодом похоже у меня была проблема из-за кодировки. я данные в cp1251 отправлял. Стал отправлять в utf-8, и проблема ушла

Comment: с саджестом наткнулся на такую проблему:
очередность объектов в поле displayName он выдает обратную нежели пользователь вводит в запросе.
Т.е. пользователь вводит, например, "Москва лесная улица",
а саджест выдает обратный порядок: "Лесная улица, Москва"
Не очень "красиво" получается. 
Есть ли пути обойти это?

Comment: Такой возможности нет